# Mapping To Correct Array When Using updateMany() and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

In my MongoDB/Node backend, I am trying to write a function that takes in user inputted IDs, and then updates a field called `subscription.subscriptionEnd` that matches for each of those passed in IDs.

The value I'm updating to is the same for all of the inputed records. My challenge is in targeting the correct element within an array called "subscription" (which is at the root of the document). What I want to do is simply update the `subcriptionEnd` property for each array element that matches for one of the inputted IDs.

My data looks like this:

```
{
        "_id": "1234",
        "name": {
            "first": "John",
            "last": "Smith"
        },
        "branch": "New York",
        "dob": null,
        "subscription": [
            {
                "field1": null,
                "field2": null,
                "subscriptionEnd": "2015-05-31T00:00:00.000Z",
                "_id": "7777"
            },
            {
                "field1": null,
                "field2": null,
                "subscriptionEnd": "2015-05-31T00:00:00.000Z",
                "_id": "9999"
            }
        ]
}
```

So, imagine a case where I want to update the "subscriptionEnd" property value only for the array element that has an "_id" of "7777", but not for the one that has an "_id" of "9999".

How can I make these these map correctly? A commenter yesterday mentioning mapping dynamically, by doing something like this:

```
db.collection('clients').updateMany( 
 { _id: { $in: mongoArrRecords }, "subscription.someOtherProp":value},
 { $set: { "subscription.$.subscriptionEnd": lastDayOfMonth } }
)
```

But I'm unclear what's mapping to what in this case. Is there a way I can ensure that this maps correctly - targeting only the same array element that contains one of the inputted IDs?

Of course, if I *knew* what array element was in question, I could target directly, like this:

```
db.collection('clients').updateMany( 
 { _id: { $in: mongoArrRecords } },
 { $set: { "subscription.0.subscriptionEnd": lastDayOfMonth } }
)
```

But I don't know this.

What I *do* know is that it's the same array element where the `_id` being passed in as part of an array via the `$in` operator is mapping to.

Comment: yes it will target the correct element. Try `db.collection('clients').updateMany( 
 { _id: { $in: mongoArrRecords }, "subscription._id":"7777"},
 { $set: { "subscription.$.subscriptionEnd": lastDayOfMonth } }
)` for your case.

Comment: Right, but to clarify, I won't know the value. So I can't hardcode "7777". It will need to map dynamically according to the IDs that are coming via $in: mongoArrRecords.

Comment: I think you can do that too. Can you show us sample of mongoArrRecords ?

Comment: That can vary, because it's an array being passed in by a user. So it could be [7777, 4444, 3333, 5656, 2345, 6574], etc. I'm using made up numbers here, just remember it's an array of mongo object IDs.

Comment: How this question is different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49309816/traversing-the-document-correctly-when-updating-array-elements-with-updatemany ?

Comment: Try `db.collection('clients').updateMany( { "subscription._id":{ $in: mongoArrRecords }}, { $set: { "subscription.$.subscriptionEnd": lastDayOfMonth } } )` This should work as long as your targeting one objectid for one array

Comment: That worked perfectly, @Veeram. If you want to add it as an answer I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work with two array properties. One array property to query and another array property to update.

Try

```
db.collection('clients').updateMany( 
   { "subscription._id":{ $in: mongoArrRecords }}, 
   { $set: { "subscription.$.subscriptionEnd": lastDayOfMonth } } 
)
```

This should work as long as your targeting one objectid for one array.

You can extend the above method with [`[<identifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/index.html) to target multi array elements inside a single document using arrayFilters concept in 3.6.

```
db.collection('clients').updateMany(
   { },
   { $set: { "subscription.$[subr].subscriptionEnd" : lastDayOfMonth  } },
   {
     arrayFilters: [{ "subr._id":{ $in: mongoArrRecords }} ]
   }
)
```